# Java server (Tomcat 9.0.48) Ignores ${} this expression

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, tomcat, web-applications

I am relatively new to Java web-development and I'm trying to execute JavaScript code in a JSP file, i.e `${(format.date)}`, but when I view the source code on my web-browser it completely ignores the expression `${}`.

Any particular reason why the server is ignoring it? How do I overcome this?

```
<Script>
${(format.date)}
</Script>
```

FYI: `format.date` is just a random syntax but the server would still ignore anything that would be inside curly brackets.

Comment: is format.date coming through a javascript code or Java code?

Answer (score 0):

The server ignore the syntax, because it doesn't find a variable in any scope.

```
<c:set var="pattern">MM/dd/YYYY</c:set>
<fmt:formatDate value="${format.date}" pattern="${pattern}"/>
```